# How do I Import a .proto file from a dependency jar using gradle

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers

I have a project that creates a set of protobuf objects and GRPC stubs.

I have a dependency on a jar with other .proto files in it, that I would like to use in my project.

ie:

project-abc-0.0.1.jar contains a file: /some-types.proto 
It contains these pieces:

```
package foo_companyname;
message StatusItem {
    string status = 1;
    string statusDescription = 2;
}
```

my project has a build.gradle file where I am trying to import it like so:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.companyname', name: 'project-abc', version: '0.0.1')
}
```

Then, inside my new "enhanced-status.proto" I'm doing this:

```
import "foo_companyname/some-types.proto";

message EnhancedStatus{
    string author = 1;
    repeated StatusItem status = 2;
}
```

If I don't reference the other .proto, everything works fine - I'm able to generate all the correct java any python classes. As soon as I add it, I'm getting this:

```
Execution failed for task ':generateProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: foo_companyname/some-types.proto: File not found.
  enhanced-status.proto: Import "foo_companyname/some-types.proto" was not found or had errors.
  enhanced-status.proto:26:19: "StatusItem" is not defined.
```

I'm assuming there's some trick to getting gradle or protoc to find .proto sources that are in a jar file? Or do I need to extract the jar file's .proto into my own /proto dir? That would cause a conflict, since the jar has a compiled version of some-types.proto already, and I don't want to compile it again.

Comment: I solved this using a bunch of gradle hacks: I extract the .protos into the /src tree with a task, then remove them and the .class files with another task before the jar task happens. Ugh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the google protobuf gradle plugin

```
plugins {
   id 'com.google.protobuf' version "0.8.5"
}
```

You should just need to specify your dependent jar in the dependencies block (i.e, as a 'protobuf' dependency, not 'compile'):

```
dependencies {           
    protobuf "com.companyname:project-abc:0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: I had already fixed this with a bunch of gradle hacks, but I had time to revisit it lately, and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) supports protobuf files in dependencies:

> If a compile configuration has a dependency on a project or library jar that contains proto files, they will be added to the `--proto_path` flag of the `protoc` command line, so that they can be imported in the proto files of the dependent project. The imported proto files will not be compiled since they have already been compiled in their own projects.

Comment: I'm already using it:

        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'

Comment: In this case, maybe your path is wrong. Where is the imported `.proto` file located inside the `.jar` file?

Comment: It's at the root of the jar file. I've also tried : import "some-types.proto"; and there's no difference.

Comment: @Kylar I'm facing the same issue. I'm not able to import the .proto file from a dependency. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the package name foo_companyname for using StatusItem message, try in this way:

```
import "foo_companyname/some-types.proto";

message EnhancedStatus{
    string author = 1;
    repeated foo_companyname.StatusItem status = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is pointed out that the [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) would do the job, but I still can't understand how to specify the path of the dependency proto file in my own proto file. I figured it out through trial and error, and here it is:

First, use Protobuf Plugin for Gradle and add the library jar that contains proto files as `implementation` dependency:

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.17"
    id "java"
    id "maven-publish"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.12.2"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-all:1.49.1"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
    implementation "my.company:common-schema:1.0.14"  // <-- this is my library
}
```

Next, try to build the project by running `assemble` or `build` task.
Then have a look at the `build` folder generated by the build, you will find an `extracted-include-protos` folder that contains the proto files from the library. In my IntelliJ window it looks like this:

[image]

Include any proto file into your proto file using the path from above folder structure. To use a type from imported proto, use its fully qualified type name, like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "grpc/currency/Currency.proto";  <-- proto file from library
import "grpc/country/Country.proto";    <-- proto file from library

package com.mycompany.myservice;

message MyMessage {
  ...
  com.mycompany.common.currency.CurrencyCode currency = 11;
  ...
}
```

Finally, run another build and your proto files should get compiled successfully.

P.S. I don't know why the `main` folder in the above structure is disregarded, so you may have to try several times to find out what is working. Another minor thing: IntelliJ still highlights the import statements in red (can't resolve the file), but the build is successful and that's good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

1. Add the JAR as a dependency (as you have done)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.companyname', name: 'project-abc', version: '0.0.1')
}
```

2. Import the proto file directly *without* the package name (see what @Lukas mentioned)

```
import "some-types.proto";
```

3. Reference the model in the imported proto file with the package name

```
message EnhancedStatus {
    string author = 1;
    repeated foo_companyname.StatusItem status = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same case and no one here answers works for me.
that actions helps me:

1. add include("build/extracted-include-protos/main/data/*.proto")

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.1.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.38.0")
    implementation("my-external-lib-with-compiled-proto-jar") //!!!!
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.2"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.38.0"
        }
        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.1.0:jdk7@jar"
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().forEach {
                it.plugins {
                    id("grpc")
                    id("grpckt")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDirs("src/main/proto")
            include("build/extracted-include-protos/main/data/*.proto")//!!!
        }
        java {
            java.srcDir("build/generated/source/proto/main/java")
            java.srcDir("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc")
            java.srcDir("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt")
        }
      }
   }
```

2. to make external proto green in current proto we can add in Idea settings Languages/Protobuf/.. path to your YOUR_PATH/lib/build/extracted-include-protos/main, fox example:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvRPo.png)