# Gradle protobuf task not picking up definitions from dependencies

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I have a situation where I have two Gradle subprojects that are basically dumb protobuf containers. One sub project needs to import the definitions from the other, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the protobuf Gradle plugin to work correctly (I'm fairly new to Gradle).

Here's an example.

Directory layout:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
gradle.properties
dependency/
|
 - build.gradle
 - src/main/proto/dependency.proto
 main/
|
 - build.gradle
 - src/main/proto/main.proto
```

build.gradle (top level)

```
plugins {
  id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.12"
  id "java"
}

configure (allprojects) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'sample'

include 'main'
include 'dependency'
```

gradle.properties

```
group=sample
version=0.1.0
```

dependency/build.gradle

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.4'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.11.4'
}
```

dependency/src/main/proto/dependency.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package dependency;

option java_package = "dependency";

message DependencyRequest {
        string foo = 1;
}

message DependencyResponse {
        string bar = 1;
}
```

main/build.gradle

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.27.2'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.4'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.11.4'

    protobuf project(':dependency')
}
```

main/src/main/proto/main.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package main;

option java_package = "main";

import "dependency/dependency.proto";

service MainService {

    rpc CallDependency(DependencyRequest) returns (DependencyResponse) {}

}
```

When I try to build, I get this error:

```
$ ./gradlew :main:compileJava
> Task :main:generateProto FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':main:generateProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: dependency/dependency.proto: File not found.
  main.proto:7:1: Import "dependency/dependency.proto" was not found or had errors.
  main.proto:11:24: "DependencyRequest" is not defined.
  main.proto:11:52: "DependencyResponse" is not defined.
```

I read [documentation for the plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#protos-in-dependencies) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691843/how-do-i-import-a-proto-file-from-a-dependency-jar-using-gradle), but I haven't been able to get it to work. Any idea why the protobuf task isn't picking up dependency.proto?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the protobuf files were getting set up correctly, but there was a mismatch in the package names that cause the main.proto to not be able to find dependency.proto. I was able to get this working by removing the package names in the protobuf definitions.

If anyone runs into this problem in the future, check your package names and imports to make sure they're correct.