# Import proto files from classpath (JAR) to build another proto file

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, proto

I want to import a proto file from a **gradle dependencies** and have next structure (simplified for redability):

```
dependency-project:
     - models:
           catalog.proto
   
my-project:
     - source:
           client.proto
```

In a `client.proto` I want to reuse some models, which defined in a `catalog.proto`.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package client;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
import "classpath/catalog.proto"; // ???
...
```

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:$protoBufCoreVersion")
    implementation("com.thesamet.scalapb.common-protos:proto-google-common-protos-scalapb_0.9_2.13:2.5.0-3") // trying to reuse
}

apply(plugin = "com.google.protobuf")

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protoBufCoreVersion"
        /// probably here I need to use new lib
    }
}
...
```

But have next problems:

1. I can see `catalog.proto` in a classpath, but cannot import it from scratch
2. `catalog.proto` don't have any `package` declaration

As far as I know, there are some [available solutions for scala](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/third-party-protos/), but I'm using gradle in Java/Kotlin project with gradle and don't understand how to reuse such approach. Also, I found that such usage of proto files (for building new models using `.proto` files) is [not convinient](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/6-ZI709ruFc/m/insW598rXlIJ). Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still need it: you need to use [Protobuf Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin), check out my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73822802/2185783.